# Addon that implements edge/face groups similar to the vertex group feature?

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, faces, vertex-groups

I've found the vertex group feature very handy, but it only saves vertices, making it difficult to save edges or faces. Can somebody point me to an addon that lets me save edge/face selections?

Comment: ? edges and faces are made of vertices... vertex group CAN save faces, edges and single vertices... how different should it work to help you better?

Comment: Ok, say if i have 3 faces, and I only want to save the left and right faces, [like this](http://i.imgur.com/KIbrmJX.png). The vertex group only selects vertices, so it converts this selection to vertex selection. Since the middle square is also comprised of the vertices of the left and right square, [it will also be selected](http://i.imgur.com/z20iFVx.png).

Comment: ok, now I get it, if nothing else works, you could use multiple vertex groups...

Comment: @m.ardito Vertex groups aren't always enough unfortunately, they don't unequivocally define edge or face groups. There are no native builtin structures in blender that allow saving edges or groups as far as I know. For faces there is one workaround, that is using material slots as a way to save groups of faces, though one face can olny belong to one slot at each time.

Comment: yes, probably some addon could be made to use something simple like empties, hooked to edges or faces, to keep those mesh elements distinct but being able to reverse the empty -> hook -> mesh elements direction... which is not possible, atm, I fear...

Comment: This is a feature I'd really like too, and I've considered trying to write a script for it, cause it doesn't seem like it'd be too hard. I've also wondered about using the "custom data" stuff, but I don't really know how that works or whether it would suffice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51296/is-there-a-way-to-save-selection-by-faces

Comment: For faces could  set up a [custom layer](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Mesh.html?highlight=polygon_layers#bpy.types.Mesh.polygon_layers_string)  (which I assume is what @CodyReisdorf 's means by "custom data" stuff)