# Select side faces only

Tags: selection-tools, vertex-groups

When I select the walls and assign them as a vertex group and then select this vertex group it selects the wall but the floor too. How can I make it select only the walls ?

[image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51296/is-there-a-way-to-save-selection-by-faces. It's not possible to use vertex groups to select just walls given that geometry

Answer (score 0):

You need modifie topology like this [image]