# Problem with vertices and unwanted addition of adjacent faces

Tags: modeling

I have had this happen before and am not sure how to fix it. Here are the events:
1. Model an object.
2. Select a row of faces that circumvent the entire (cube) object.
3. Create a vertex group.
4. Assign the vertices to the group.

My problem is that sometimes, not always, adjacent faces are automatically included in the vertex group. It seems to occur most often when I have assigned a similar vertex group to faces one row (or column I suppose) away from the vertices I want included in the group. Thanks ahead for any suggestions.

Comment: If you mean saving to vertex group using faces' bounds then related (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51296/is-there-a-way-to-save-selection-by-faces)

Comment: This answered my question completely. Thank you.