# Bevel only certain edges with Bevel Modifier

Tags: bevel

I am trying to bevel only some edges on my cube and I manage to do so with the bevel **tool**, but I fail with the bevel **modifier**. I tried adding those edges, which I also selected when using the tool, to a vertex group and applying the modifier only to those, but still all edges get beveled in the result. I understand that this happens because the vertices and not the edges are in the vertex group, but I don't know how to work around this.

How can I achieve the same result with the modifier as with the tool?

[image: make right box looks same as left box]

Am using blender 2.8

Comment: It's not possible to add vertices sharing the same edges to a vertex group and avoid selecting edges they hold in between; see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51296/is-there-a-way-to-save-selection-by-faces

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with the *Vertex Group* method, but if you choose *Weight*, then set the edges weight in the *N* panel, it works.

[image]